# discord.py lots of "cog" errors

Tags: python, discord.py

trying to make a global banning system with cogs but it gives me cog errors and im not too good with cog. the code is from an old github repo by the way so i dont take credit for this.

bot.py:

```py
import discord
import os
import json
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".") 
client.remove_command("help")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Global Banning System is online!")

for filename in os.listdir("cogs"):
   if filename.endswith(".py"):
      client.load_extension(f"cogs.gbs")     

client.run(token)
```

and i also have another file in a new folder ("cogs") that is called "gbs.py".
gbs.py:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class gbs(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_role(roleid) # Staff's Role
    async def gban(self, ctx, member: discord.User):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(channelid) # Logs
        auth = ctx.author

        await ctx.send("Ban Issue successfuly opened. Now, please type the ban reason!")
        reason = await self.client.wait_for('message', timeout = 600)

        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Global Banned {member.name}", colour = 0xFF0000)
        embed.add_field(name = "Reason:", value = reason.content, inline = False)
        embed.add_field(name = "User ID:", value = f"`{member.id}`",)
        embed.add_field(name = "Staff Member:", value = f"{auth.name}")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url = member.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        await ctx.send(f"**{member.name}** has been globbaly banned!")
        for guild in self.gbs.guilds:
            await guild.ban(member)

def setup(client):
  gbs.add_cog(gbs(client))
```

This is the errors that it gives me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user-01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\cog.py", line 723, in _load_from_module_spec
    setup(self)
  File "C:\Users\user-01\Desktop\Global Banning System - Discord Bot\cogs\gbs.py", line 28, in setup
    gbs.add_cog(gbs(client))
AttributeError: type object 'gbs' has no attribute 'add_cog'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user-01\Desktop\Global Banning System - Discord Bot\bot.py", line 15, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.gbs")
  File "C:\Users\user-01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\cog.py", line 783, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\user-01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\cog.py", line 728, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.gbs' raised an error: AttributeError: type object 'gbs' has no attribute 'add_cog'
```

Answer (score 1):

You add a cog class to your bot not to your gbs. So replace gbs with client to solve the problem.

```py
def setup(client):
    # instead of gbs.add_cog...
    client.add_cog(gbs(client))
```

[Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html#cog-registration)